# Connection dropped error on Redis upgrade in Heroku. Failure through rx-sync

Tags: node.js, ssl, heroku, redis, tcp

I'm updating to Redis 7 on my Heroku app, and for some reason I'm getting this TCP read error. I keep getting 503 errors on my server.

My site comes up when I navigate to it, but I can do things like sign-in or make an account.

Error -

```
2023-05-26T17:39:08.000000+00:00 app[redis-cylindrical-25648]: Error accepting a client connection: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number (conn: fd=17)
2023-05-26T17:39:08.000000+00:00 app[redis-cylindrical-25648]: Error accepting a client connection: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number (conn: fd=17)
2023-05-26T17:39:08.000000+00:00 app[redis-cylindrical-25648]: Error accepting a client connection: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number (conn: fd=17)
2023-05-26T17:39:09.000000+00:00 app[redis-cylindrical-25648]: Error accepting a client connection: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number (conn: fd=17)
2023-05-26T17:39:09.000000+00:00 app[redis-cylindrical-25648]: Error accepting a client connection: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number (conn: fd=17)
2023-05-26T17:39:09.000000+00:00 app[redis-cylindrical-25648]: Error accepting a client connection: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number (conn: fd=17)
2023-05-26T17:39:09.000000+00:00 app[redis-cylindrical-25648]: Error accepting a client connection: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number (conn: fd=17)
2023-05-26T17:39:09.000000+00:00 app[redis-cylindrical-25648]: Error accepting a client connection: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number (conn: fd=17)
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400044+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: read ECONNRESET
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400057+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20) {
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400058+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -104,
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400058+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNRESET',
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400058+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'read'
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400059+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400546+00:00 app[web.1]: AbortError: Ready check failed: Redis connection lost and command aborted. It might have been processed.
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400549+00:00 app[web.1]: at RedisClient.flush_and_error (/app/server/node_modules/rx-sync/node_modules/redis/index.js:362:23)
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400550+00:00 app[web.1]: at RedisClient.connection_gone (/app/server/node_modules/rx-sync/node_modules/redis/index.js:664:14)
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400550+00:00 app[web.1]: at RedisClient.on_error (/app/server/node_modules/rx-sync/node_modules/redis/index.js:410:10)
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400550+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/server/node_modules/rx-sync/node_modules/redis/index.js:279:14)
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400551+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400551+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (domain.js:475:12)
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400552+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400552+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400561+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400562+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'UNCERTAIN_STATE',
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400562+00:00 app[web.1]: command: 'INFO',
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400562+00:00 app[web.1]: origin: Error: read ECONNRESET
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400563+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20) {
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400563+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -104,
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400563+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNRESET',
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400563+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'read'
2023-05-26T17:39:09.400564+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

redis.ts -

```
import * as redis from 'redis'
import configService, { ENV_REDIS_URL } from '../config/config.service'
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common'

const redisURL = configService.get(ENV_REDIS_URL)
const redisOptions = {
    url: redisURL,
    ...(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && { tls: { rejectUnauthorized: false } })
}

const redisClient = redis.createClient(redisOptions)
const subscribeClient = redisClient.duplicate();
```

redis-io.adapter.ts -

```
import { IoAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-socket.io'
import * as redisIoAdapter from 'socket.io-redis'
import configService, { ENV_REDIS_URL } from '../config/config.service'
import { INestApplicationContext,Logger } from '@nestjs/common'

const redisURL = configService.get(ENV_REDIS_URL)
const redisOptions = {
    url: redisURL,
    ...(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && { tls: { rejectUnauthorized: false } })
}

const redisAdapter = redisIoAdapter(redisOptions)

export class RedisIoAdapter extends IoAdapter {
  constructor(appOrHttpServer: INestApplicationContext | any) {
    super(appOrHttpServer)
  }

  createIOServer(port: number, options?: any): any {
    const server = super.createIOServer(port, options)
    server.adapter(redisAdapter)
    
    return server
   }
}
```

I've tried updating my ssl (self signed) and everything seems to be fine on that end.